# the onMessageReceived callback is not called on Android

Tags: android, typescript, push-notification, nativescript

I have the following nativescript+typescript+angular code inside a simple app.component.ts example. The problem is that the settings.notificationCallbackAndroid is never called, i do not see any output in the console. The registration process completes correctly, i receive the token and i can get push notifications, but the android callback is not triggered.. any hint?

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as pushPlugin from "nativescript-push-notifications";

var Observable = require("data/observable");

@Component({
selector: "my-app",
template: `

  <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
  </ActionBar>    
<StackLayout (loaded)="pageLoaded()">>
<Label text="Tap the button to trigger the register function." textWrap="true" class=""></Label>
<Button text="REGISTER" (tap)="registerTap()" ></Button>    
<label text="Your device id/token:" textWrap="true" ></label>
<TextView text={{viewModel.registrationId}} class="title" textWrap="true"></TextView>
<Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true" ></Label>
</StackLayout>

`
})
export class AppComponent {


viewModel = new Observable.Observable({
registrationId: ""
});



handleMessage(){
alert('handle');
}


pageLoaded() {
  this.viewModel.set("registrationId", "");      

}

//args
registerTap () {



 let settings = {
    // Android settings 
    senderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // Android: Required setting with the     sender/project number 
    notificationCallbackAndroid: (message, data, notification) => {
            console.log("MESSAGE: " + JSON.stringify(message));
            console.log("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("NOTIFICATION: " + JSON.stringify(notification));
    },


    // iOS settings 
    badge: true, // Enable setting badge through Push Notification 
    sound: true, // Enable playing a sound 
    alert: true, // Enable creating a alert 

    // Callback to invoke, when a push is received on iOS 
    notificationCallbackIOS: message => {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(message));
    }
};




pushPlugin.register(settings,
    // Success callback 

//equivale a function(token)
    token => {
       // if we're on android device we have the onMessageReceived function to subscribe 
        // for push notifications 
        if(pushPlugin.onMessageReceived) {
            alert("sono qui");
            pushPlugin.onMessageReceived(
                settings.notificationCallbackAndroid                    
            );

        }

       // alert('Device registered successfully : ' + token);
       this.viewModel.set("registrationId", token);     
        alert('Device registered successfully : '+ this.viewModel.registrationId); 
    },    
    // Error Callback 

    error =>{
        alert("errore");
        //console.log(error);
        alert(error);
    }

);
}



}
```

Comment: Does having the app in the background or foreground make a difference? i.e. does this still happen if the app is foregrounded?

Comment: yes unfortunately. I should add that i'm running it on an emulator